# AWS-Lamda node js not pushing metrics in AWS, works when run locally

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I need build an aws lambda that checks to see if a port is open on a host, then pushes a "0" or "1" as a cloud metric.
I am a complete novice with node js, and after hours of googling, I was able to cobble together a js file that works when I run it locally on my desktop.
When I run the js file from my local desktop, it works. It checks the host and pushes the metric correctly. When I upload the zip of my project as a lamba it fails. I did verify that if a remove the "putmetricdata" section and its related var statements, it will check the port successfully. I really feel like I dont have any idea what I am doing, any help is appreciated!

> Response
> {
> "errorMessage": "2021-04-01T19:00:39.949Z d2c3a983-94e4-4179-b326-5b921f8413e6 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds"
> }

```
'use strict';

var lambdaHandler = function(event, context, callback) {
    const connData = {
        port: 5555,
        host: '10.10.10.10',
        timeout: 75
    };

    const timeout = typeof connData.timeout !== 'undefined' ?
                    parseInt(connData.timeout) :
                    50; // Fallback to 50ms
    const net = require('net');
    var available = 0;
    var message = 'Whoops port ' + connData.port + ' on host ' +
                  connData.host + ' seems closed! ' + available;
    
    const client = net.connect(connData, function() {
      available = 1;
      message = 'Port ' + connData.port + ' on ' + connData.host + ' is open!' + available;

      callback(null, message);

      client.destroy();
    });

    client.setTimeout(timeout, function() {
        client.destroy(new Error(message), null);
    });

    client.on('error', function(err) {
        callback(new Error(message), null);
    });
    var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
    AWS.config.update({region: 'us-gov-west-1'});
    var cw = new AWS.CloudWatch({apiVersion: '2010-08-01'});
    var params = {
  MetricData: [
    {
      MetricName: 'TCPHealthCheck',
      Dimensions: [
        {
          Name: 'HOST',
          Value: '10.141.8.15'
        },
        {
          Name: 'PORT',
          Value: '5444'
        },
      ],
      Unit: 'None',
      Value: available
    },
  ],
  Namespace: 'Route53PrivateHealthCheck'
};

cw.putMetricData(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Success", JSON.stringify(data));
  }
});
};

exports.checkPortOpen = lambdaHandler;

if (require.main === module) {
    var lambdaContext = {
        context: {
            'my-host': process.env.MY_HOST,
            'my-port': process.env.MY_PORT,
            'my-timeout': process.env.MY_TIMEOUT
        }
    };

    lambdaHandler(lambdaContext, null, function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
           return null;
        }

        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Is your Lambda running inside VPC?

Comment: yes it is, attached to a subnet in av-zone A

Comment: Try adding a NAT gateway

Comment: I verified that the subnet for the lambda is associated with a route table that points to the NAT gateway for its default route.

Comment: I also tried adding a monitoring endpoint and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

The error given says it is a time out

> Response { "errorMessage": "2021-04-01T19:00:39.949Z d2c3a983-94e4-4179-b326-5b921f8413e6 Task timed out after 3.00 seconds" }

Default timeout for Lambda is 3 seconds, you can change this configuration up to 15 minutes in the General Configuration section of your Lambda.